# Is it possible to check if method is overriden from superclass easier?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I am trying to create simple Java obfuscator for the sake of creating it using OW2's ASM to modify the bytecode at runtime.

My target is to rename every class, field and method name but I can't figure out how to detact if the MethodNode exists in superclass easily

I am currently recursively looping through every super class in current class and seeing if method exists with same name and signature

```
private boolean isSuperMethod(MethodNode method, ClassNode node) {
    if(node.superName == null)
        return false;
    boolean exists = false;
    ClassNode cn = null;
    try {
        ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(node.superName);
        cn = new ClassNode();
        cr.accept(cn, 0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for(MethodNode superMethod: (List<MethodNode>)cn.methods) {
        boolean sameSignature = (superMethod.signature == null && method.signature == null) || superMethod.signature.equals(method.signature);
        if(superMethod.name.equals(method.name) && sameSignature) {
            System.out.println(superMethod.name + " exists in parent class(" + cn.name + ")");
            exists = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return exists || isSuperMethod(method, cn);
}
```

Is there a cleaner or faster way to achieve this because this seems like overkill?

Comment: You could check for the Override annotation instead (which isn't guaranteed in all cases but common practice).

Comment: I thought about that but if they don't exist and I am renaming method I am screwed :/

Comment: I'm quite sure what you are doing is similar to how the JVM finds overriden methods. There is nothing it can do during compilation after all, since you might change the super-class at some point and thus change the results of the lookup.

Comment: Your code won't work fully, btw, because it doesn't take covariance or contravariance into consideration. For instance, if a superclass's method returns Object, a subclass is allowed to override it returning String.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen so this isn't bad after all?

Comment: @yshavit I didn't quite get that one..? My target is to rename methods that haven't been defined on superclass

Comment: I meant that comparing if the two signatures are equal isn't enough, as you may miss some overrides. Specifically, they'll look like overloads when they're actually overrides.

Comment: @yshavit: if they haven’t the same signature they are not overrides.

Comment: @Ruuhkis: don’t forget to check whether a method implements an interface method

Comment: @Holger Unless raw types come into play: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2

Comment: @yshavit: this is a Java language issue which is not important regarding the JVM (especially when doing obfuscation). On byte code level you are looking at the raw type signatures only and if the compiler generated a bridge method that’s no problem. You may give the bridge method a name different to the delegate and in the context of obfuscation you may even *want* that to confuse disassemblers. The JVM does not care…

Comment: Yes, you're right. Sorry, I didn't fully re-read the thread before I replied to you, so I forgot this was a bytecode question. I think what I was referring to back then was the method signature + return type -- which I admit is not formally part the signature, but is informally often thrown in there.

Comment: What you are doing is right in essence, but you should not compare signatures, but rather desc's. The way overriding works in Java, it does not take generics into account.

Answer (score 0):

When the JVM loads a class, it organizes these class's methods in a so-called method table. This method table identifies each method by its name and descriptor. What you do is therefore the only way to determine an overridden method. (Checking for the `Overridden` annotation is not a solution as this annotation is not preserved in the compiled class, it only serves as an instruction to the Java compiler.)

This becomes more obvious when you think about a class `B extends A` where class `A` is changed after `B` was already compiled. If `B` had overridden a method of `A`, this is not necessarily still true after the recompilation.

One thing however, the *signature* of a method is irrelevant for a method being overridden. You should instead check the *descriptor*.